# What is the current status of the taxon Crocodylus raninus?

Tags: zoology, taxonomy, herpetology

What is the current status of the taxon *Crocodylus raninus*, the Borneo Crocodile? See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodylus_raninus) Is it now a valid species, a subspecies of *Crocodylus porosus* (The Saltwater Crocodile) or merely a synonym of the later?

As for Colin Stevenson, "*Crocodiles of the World*, Reed New Holland 2019", it is not listed as a (valid) species, nor in the [IUCN Crocodile Specialist Group](http://www.iucncsg.org/pages/Crocodilian-Species.html).

Comment: I started to dig into this a little bit.  I think the answer is probably "it's very uncertain". I don't actually know if there's an **official** (rather than a scholarly) standard for validity;  I couldn't find anything at https://www.iczn.org/outreach/faqs/ ...